# cant read data from tcp port

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

i have written code for reading data from tcp port 3000

```
- (BOOL)connect
{
int cIter = 0;
while(cIter++<5)
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    @try{
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)M_CONNECT_HOST, M_CONNECT_PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex) {

    }
    if(readStream!=nil && writeStream!=nil)
    {
        m_sin = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
        m_sout = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
        [m_sin setDelegate:self];
        [m_sout setDelegate:self];

        [m_sin scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [m_sout scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [m_sin open];
        [m_sout open];

        return  true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

When i write to tcp output stream its working but when i try to read from the tcp input stream its not reading i mean my 
    [m_sin read:t maxlength:10];
is always returning -1 (where m_sin is my input stream)

And i m passing the data to the tcp port by terminal

please Help me

Comment: And what does `[NSInputStream streamError]` return?

Comment: [NSInputStream streamError] returns "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad address"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the **handleEvent** and check it out the **eventCode**

```
 -(void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{

    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"stream opened");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:            

            if (aStream == inputStream) {
                // read it in
                unsigned int len = 0;
                len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1019];
                buf[len] = '\0';

                if(!len) {

                    if ([aStream streamStatus] != NSStreamStatusAtEnd){

                        NSLog(@"Failed reading data from peer");

                    }

                } else {

                     //I am reading UIImage here                 
                     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)buf length:1019];                    
                     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                     self.transferedimage.image = image;


                }
            }

            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"stream ErrorOccurred");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            NSLog(@"stream EndEncountered");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"stream UnKnown");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but this "case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:" case is never true

Comment: Create A Socket Based iPhone App using this tutorial first http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: or check it out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html